# Designing Ruby On Rails 4 Routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I want to achieve something like this: `/users/14/images/88` when developing my Rails application.
There I have users URL-segment, then comes user ID, and images that belong to this user, and image ID.

I'm asking you, SO, what is the best way to design my routes? Should I keep this pattern or not?
I've read this on Ruby On Rails Routing Docs:

```
[ ! ] Resources should never be nested more than 1 level deep.
```

And this is what confuses me. Not more that 1 level deep.

So, basically, this could mean that one level could be `/users/14`, but I need one more level (+ `/images/88`). And according to best practice in designing routes this is bad idea to make more-than-one-level-nested resources.
I'm confused a bit about that.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is no place to share expert **opinions**, sorry. Still, to clarify, it's about one **nesting** level: i. e. `/users/14/images/11` is acceptable, `/users/14/images/11/comments/5` is not. This is merely a code style limitation, see the [Rails Community Style Guide](https://github.com/bbatsov/rails-style-guide#routing).

Comment: Thanks, actually, I've decided to use `/users/11/images` when pointing to user's images, and if I want to get link to image, it'll be `/images/231`, so I've separated my images with their id's from users url-segment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :users do
   resources :images
end
```

This is one level deep.

---

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :users do
   resources :images do
      resources :comments
   end
end
```

This is more than one level deep.

---

As you can see by the [quoted resource](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#limits-to-nesting), the issue is not about inability to match the resource, but in handling the flow. For example...

```
#app/controllers/comments_controller.rb
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
   def show
      @user = User.find params[:user_id]
      @image = @user.images.find params[:image_id]
      @comments = @image.comments
   end
end
```

Whilst not completely out of range, it shows how confusing deep linking resources can get. You're better advocating a more streamlined approach - for example, appending `comments` to `images` & showing them through the `images#show` controller action.